# laravel project failed to load font awesome boilerplate

Tags: css, laravel, coding-style

I install laravel boilerplate and when start project , he don't load font-awesome, why ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you running `gulp` at `your-laravel-directory`

Comment: Are you running it using `php artisan serve`? What url do you access the website?

Comment: i use npm and idk why he doesn't work

Comment: Can you post up your `webpack.mix.js`, and please not a picture of it.

Comment: omg , how i don't have this file

Comment: @whoacowboy i don't have this file

Comment: What boilerplate are you using ?

Comment: @Rezrazi boilerplate 5

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install` and then `npm run dev`
And try to clear your laravel cache and/or browser cache.